# How to prove that a connected graph with $|V| -1= |E|$ is a tree?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

I could neither show myself nor find a proof of the following result:  if $G=(V,E)$ is a connected graph with $|E|=|V|-1$ then $G$ is a tree.

Could somebody please provide an argument to establish this.

Answer (score 3):

An empty graph on $n$ vertices has $n$ connected components, Suppose you have a graph and add an edge, then the number of connected components is reduced by at most one ( since this edge touches at most two connected components). Therefore a connected graph on $n$ vertices has at least $n-1$ edges).

Suppose a connected graph on  $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges, we must prove no cycle exists, suppose it does, if we remove an edge from the cycle we get a connected graph (because if we have a path that uses this edge, instead of using the edge we can go around the remaining part of the cycle). This is a contradiction, since the graph would have $n-2$ edges, and would hence not be connected.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $|V| \ge 2$. Recall that the sum of the degrees of all vertices is $2|E|$. Since The graph is connected there cannot be a vertex of degree $0$.

Thus as $2|V|> 2|E|$ there is a vertex of degree one. Removing that vertex and the adjacent edge does not change that the graph is connected. And if the graph after removal is a tree, so is the graph itself.

Using this starting idea you can set up a proof by induction.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the graph contains cycles, then we can remove an edge without removing a vertex and the graph is still connected. After removing, it will has $n$ vertices and $n - 2$ edges. Continue to do so until we reach a tree (because there is no cycle) with $n$ vertices and $n - k$ edges $(k > 1)$. However it contradicts with the fact that a tree with $n$ vertices must has $n - 1$ edges.
Therefore the graph must not contain cycles, and then it is a tree by definition.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please format questions and answers using MathJax for mathematical notation. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @platty: Thank you for informing. I have already fixed my mathematical notations.